# LINQ Group by where key is an object

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array of this object:

```
public class WorkingOrderContract : BaseContract, IEquatable<WorkingOrderContract>
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int ResourceId { get; set; }
    public virtual ResourceContract Resource { get; set; }
    public virtual CategoryContract Category { get; set; }
    public WorkingOrderEnum EWorkingOrder { get; set; }
    public TimeFlagEnum ETimeFlag { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(WorkingOrderContract other)
    {
        return this.Id == other.Id;
    }
}
```

loaded dinamically by json file.

I'm using this code to group by but it's not working

```
var woListGrupped = this._workingOrderList.GroupBy(wo => wo.Category,
                               wo => wo,
                               (k, g) => new OdlByCategoryContract(k, g.ToList())
                               ).ToList();
```

how do I do this?

Comment: What does "it´s not working" mean? What result do you get and what do you expect?

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove `wo => wo`

```
var woListGrupped = this._workingOrderList.GroupBy(wo => wo.Category,
                               (k, g) => new OdlByCategoryContract(k, g.ToList())
                               ).ToList();
```

As @MarcinJuraszek rightly pointed, in addition to this `OdlByCategoryContract` should implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in order to Group the list properly.

Comment: That's still only going to work if `CategoryContract` implements `Equals` and `GetHashCode` correctly.

Comment: Agreed @MarcinJuraszek

Comment: the solution posted MarcinJuraszek is correct... thanks

Comment: When you remove the `wo => wo` it calls an overload that boils down to putting the `wo => wo` back in.